# Getting a name id from the value of a string in android

Tags: android, string, view

I have a string I'm using in a text view for example

```
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:text="@string/yes"/>
```

I want to be able to get the key "yes" from this Textview , not the value of this string but just the key that leads to it , is there some way I can use the value  of the string to get it ?

Comment: can you explain why you want to get the "key" this way from TextView?

Comment: We are using the strings we have in the XML as a default value , but we want the actual value to come from Firebase Remote Config , so I was attempting to go through all Textviews take the "key" from them and look for the the object that has that same "key" in the returned firebase json

Answer (score 2):

there is no option for getting string resource id (you are naming it "key") after setting with `android:text`. `TextView` is resolving it in its runtime, fetching `String` and "forgets" way how it was set up. same case when setting e.g. image for `ImageView` (`android:src="@drawable/drawable_name"`) or some dimensions for all `View`s (e.g. `android:padding="@dimen/some_dimension"`)

if you really need this reference in code then it would be better to NOT set this text via XML, instead store this reference under some `final int` variable in code and use it for setting text for `TextView` programmatically, further use same variable in another place you need